# Build/Parse an XML document from a socketstream in Python

Tags: python, elementtree

I have an issue parsing a continuous stream of (multiple) xml documents sent by a third party over a socket. A sample of the xml stream sent over the socket is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><event><user id="1098"/><viewpage>109958</viewpage></event>
<?xml version="1.0"?><event><user id="1482"/><actions><edit>102865</edit><commit>1592356</commit></actions></event>
etc.
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import socket
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from StringIO import StringIO

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "IP.IP.IP.IP"
port = "8080"
addr = (host,port)
s.connect(addr)

def iparse(packet):
    for _, element in etree.iterparse(packet):
        print ("%s, %s" %(element.tag, element.text))
        element.clear()
    #if complete <event> node received, publish node

data = "<feeds>"
while 1:
    chunk = s.recv(1024)
    #replace the xml doc declarations as comments
    data += (chunk.replace("<?","<!--")).replace("?>","-->")
    iparse(StringIO(data))
```

Things work just fine...however, the `for` loop in `iparse` iterates through the entire doc each time. Is it possible for `iparse` to build and iterate through one well-formed tag node (event) as it appears over the stream instead? Note that there is no way in which I can set the chunk size to read a well-formed packet. I could use a buffer, then build the packet and only send to `iparse` once the packet is well-formed, but that would likely introduce unwanted latency? Is there a better way to handle this?

**EDIT:**

Each event is distinct but contains arbitrary nodes under the root `<event>`. `iparse` is expected to publish the latest event to an arbitrary number of subscribers within a real-time analytics graphing system.

Comment: Could you give us an example of your wanted result?

Comment: Made an edit - also to the question to better reflect the required output

Comment: I guess I can't help you.  A bit over my head at this point

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [feed parsing](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#the-feed-parser-interface) in `lxml.etree`. However, you're still going to run into problems as your document is continually growing.

Are the XML blobs separated by new line characters? If so I suggest that you buffer until you hit a new line and then send each line to an xml parser. Á la [Twisted's LineReceiver](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/protocols/basic.py#L509).

Actually, if it was me, I'd probably write this application in [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). Gluing together network services is a common use case for it for me.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to feed parser...however, the solution like you point out, will have issues as the document continues to grow. The other issue I have, is that the feed parser needs an explicit `close()` call to be re-used. Looks like I will be forced to use a buffer, then throw well-formed strings to `iparse` (which can now be re-written as `xmltree.fromstring()` instead of using `iterparse`. :(